# Utilize vuex/redux instead of db

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, vue.js, redux, vuex

*In this post I am looking for some advice/clearification regarding performance for external db (or api) vs local storage, specifically for a VueJS/React application (but that doesn't matter).*

I am developing a website where the user can list, sort and filter around 200 products. During development I have stored the data in vuex using object litteral format:

```
{
  name: "Productname",
  description: "Description of product",
  price: 20,
  student: true
}
```

My plan was to put the data in a noSQL database on production. The reasoing being it would give better performance and remove one thousand lines of code from the store. However, using (e.g.) mongoDB I would probably fetch all products on mount and put them in the store anyway.

1. If I assume all users will see all 200 products, is it a bad idea to fetch all 200 products (from api or db) to vuex/redux on mount? I mean would not risk loads of fetch calls (which could become costly) and data would be preloaded for the user. For this specific example we are talking under 10000 rows of ascii json (but I am also curious in general).
2. Lets say a user wants to filter for student-products, then could there be any benefits of doing that remotely? Why not do `products.filter(p => p.student)` in the store or a component (we already fetched all products)?
3. If 1 and 2 are true then why use an extarnal db? Is it mostly for maintaining the data stored in these places, for example adding/removing products, that we use them? Can this statement be made: "Yes, of course if you have **X** products then external storage is not needed" and if so then what is **X**?

Comment: 200 products should not become a problem to sort and filter through using code but if this list grows I would suggest using a db. A db has a lot of optimisations to store and query data quickly. If you want to write to localstorage to still have the data after closing and reopening the webapp, keep in mind that local storage has a max size of 10MB. Showing 200 products to the user should technically not be a big problem if you are just showing it as text, ux-wise it's different. If you also need to support low-end devices you might want to fetch batches of the data (e.g. when the user scrolls)

Comment: As a side-note, why not go with a relational db? It seems that you have highly fixed data with not many structural variations. Especially when you want to make relations between data objects later on (joins), relational is usually faster than document-based storage.

Comment: @Bram Thanks for the input! This is an example of the most primitive object, they actually vary quite a lot and that's why I am not going for a relational db. I do not think I will store data in localstorage, it is just over the actual session (I don't want to bother the user with gdpr consent). Yes it is not good ux-wise and thats why I won't show all at once but it will be there ready. I see your point for the low-end devices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is considered a bad idea performance wise and network wise. The advantage of using an API in this case, is that you can limit the data you send and paginate it. Most of the times a user doesn't need to see 200 items at once and can happen that the item he wants to see/update/delete is in the first ones returned, that means you sent a lot of data that didn't need to be sent. That is why you have pagination or infinite scroll (when you get to the bottom of the page and it loads more data).
2. You could first filter for the data that is already fetched and if it doesn't return anything you then could do a call to an end route that you defined in your backend and query your db there to return the data the user is searching for.
3. A user can delete is localStorage and all the items go bye bye unless they are hard coded, in which case why even use localStorage, if your data is in a db and you took all the precautions to make it secure and build the API whithout security faults, then you could make sure that your users would always have data available to them. It doesn't really matter how much **X** is suppose to be, what really matters is: Would various users have access to the same data that needs to be the same for all of them? Can the users alter the data in any way?

This is really what I've learned and you need to think more about really what your application will do. Your state manager in the frontend should be considered more of a, well, state manager. It will manage the data you fetched so you can guarantee one source of truth for your application.

I hope this somewhat helps, and I would also appreciate if someone with more experience could explain it better or tell me why I'm wrong.

Comment: So we fetch only when we know that the user explicitly needs that information, and assume less i.e. only fetch some at start. I like that!

Comment: Yes you can limit it for example to 10 items, and even give the option to fetch 20 or 50, You would then provably have a URL like this `mydomain.yo/items?page=0&pagesize=10`.